# Is std::istringstream::peek() supposed to set the eof flag?

Tags: c++, c++20, stringstream, istringstream

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void print_flags(std::istringstream & iss)
{
   std::cout << "good: " << iss.good() << ", eof: " << iss.eof() << ", fail: " << iss.fail() << ", bad: " << iss.bad() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("A");
    char chr;
    iss >> chr;
    print_flags(iss);
    iss.peek();
    print_flags(iss);
}
```

On both g++ and clang++ I see the following output:

```
good: 1, eof: 0, fail: 0, bad: 0
good: 0, eof: 1, fail: 0, bad: 0
```

The [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) article does not mention that `peek` modifies the flags. It mentions the flags being modified by `get`: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Is this behaviour correct with regards to the standard?

Comment: `peek` "behaves as *UnformattedInputFunction*". If you [follow the link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction), you'll see that *UnformattedInputFunction* has a side effect of setting `eofbit`

Comment: Right, I missed this detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a requirement on [*UnformattedInputFunction*](https://eel.is/c++draft/istream.unformatted#1).

First, description of [`peek`](https://eel.is/c++draft/istream.unformatted#lib:peek,basic_istream) (emphasis mine):

> Effects: Behaves as an **unformatted input function** (as described above).
> After constructing a sentry object, reads but does not extract the current input character.
> Returns: `traits​::​eof()` if `good()` is `false`.
> Otherwise, **returns `rdbuf()->sgetc()`**.

Then, from description of [*UnformattedInputFunction*](https://eel.is/c++draft/istream.unformatted#1) above (emphasis mine):

> [...] If `rdbuf()->sbumpc()` or **`rdbuf()->sgetc()`** returns `traits​::​eof()`, then **`ios_base​::​eofbit` is set** in the local error state and the input function stops trying to obtain the requested input. [...]